# IBM mobilefist 8.0 mfpconsole not loading properly after installation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I'm new to IBM mobilefirst installation.

I installed MFP using command-line on DEV environment.
We have shared partition on VM where we are installaling. 
**Linux** : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)
**Java** - java version "1.7.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.8.1.el6_8-x86_64 u121-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.121-b00, mixed mode)

I installed Installation manager, WAS liberty core 8.5, MFP 8.0, with command line on linux.

Finally did :
./ant -f /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/MobileFirstServer/configuration-samples/configure-liberty-oracle.xml
./ant -f /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/MobileFirstServer/configuration-samples/configure-liberty-oracle.xml **databases**
./ant -f /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/MobileFirstServer/configuration-samples/configure-liberty-oracle.xml **install**

For install getting below error:

```
Buildfile: /opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/MobileFirstServer/configuration-samples/configure-liberty-oracle.xml

adminstall:
[installmobilefirstadmin] [24/01/2018 10:58:03:001 MYT] Logging output of task <installmobilefirstadmin> to file /root/.mobilefirst_platform_server/configuration-logs/installmobilefirstadmin_2018_01_24_10_58_02.log
Enter the password of MobileFirst Configuration user
[installmobilefirstadmin] [24/01/2018 10:58:22:937 MYT] JEE features detected: JEE6='true', JEE7='false';
[installmobilefirstadmin] [24/01/2018 10:58:22:938 MYT] JEE features already configured: JEE6='true', JEE7='false';
[installmobilefirstadmin] [24/01/2018 10:58:22:939 MYT] JEE features being configured: JEE6='true', JEE7='false'.

BUILD FAILED
/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/MobileFirstServer/configuration-samples/configure-liberty-oracle.xml:144: User admin is declared several times with different passwords.
```

I am able to login to mfpconsole but its just loading dashboard. Unable to register application.

getting error : **Connection error. Contact the server administrator (HTTP code: 405)**

what this m i missing.

Comment: Your installation does not appear to have succeeded, specially the admin services component. Verify your configuration file , based on this line in the log:

/opt/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/MobileFirstServer/configuration-samples/configure-liberty-oracle.xml:144: User admin is declared several times with different passwords.

Comment: vivin - I have VM which has partition. This server has other partition which has already mfp and websphere installed. I wanted to install websphere on new partition of same server. can we do that?

Comment: Yes. But when you run app server instances from both the installations together, ensure there are no port conflicts.